# onLocationChanged when using FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener) it has been stated clearly that `LocationListener` "Used for receiving notifications from `FusedLocationProviderApi` when the location has changed". On the other hand `FusedLocationProviderApi` has been marked as deprecated and they recommended to use `FusedLocationProviderClient`. Then, how to detect when a location has changed when using `FusedLocationProviderClient`?.

I need that because if I only use the `requestLocationUpdate callback`, it will update the value regardless of whether the location value changes or not.
I only need changes in location values. That way, it won't waste if I update the location value to the database. In short, updating the location values only that location changes. instead of updating location values based on time span.

The Code:

```
private void createLocationCallback() {
    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            //every 5 seconds
            mLastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            updateUI();//need onLocationChanged

        }
    };
}

private void startLocationUpdates(){
    Log.e(TAG, "startLocationUpdate");
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `LocationRequest`, you can use [setSmallestDisplacement](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)).
Example

```
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10) // 10 meters. location callback only fired when location change more than 10 metter
```

Another thing is the location accuracy can not 100% so sometime you put don't move the phone but location still change.

Comment: how about setInterval locationRequest.setInterval() and locationRequest.setFastestInterval() ?. should I delete it?

Comment: This work. I set locationRequest.setInterval(10000), locationRequest.setFastestInterva(5000), and locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10), the database changed after I walked + - 15 m

Comment: yes, `setInterval`, `setFastestInterval` and `setSmallestDisplacement` can combine. Because, they use for different purpose. There is many way to combine it , each way will give you different result. Therefore, you should understand about each function, then combine it to achieve your expectation.